# Dart Language: Creating and accessing dynamic Lists

Tags: list, arraylist, dart

I'm having some trouble when creating Lists dynamically.

For example, when we create a List this way...

```
List testList = [["John", 100], ["Maria", 200]]; // Some Strings and integers.
```

(or)

```
testList.add(["John", 100]);
testList.add(["Maria", 200]);
```

... we can access the List's info and entries by (using print)...

```
testList.length; // That returns: 2
testList; // That returns: [[John, 100], [Maria, 200]]
testList[0]; // That returns: [John, 100]
testList[1]; // That returns: [Maria, 200]
```

So far, nothing new (at least for me). But there's something interesting that I'm not being able to reproduce through some dynamic code (I'll explain it later).

If you try to access that List as some kind of multidimensional List/Array, it will work. I wasn't expecting that, as I read a lot of tutorials saying that Dart could not handle this kinds of Lists/Arrays natively. Let's take a look using print again...

```
testList[0]; // Again, that returns: [John, 100]
testList[1]; // Again, that returns: [Maria, 200]
testList[0][0]; // That returns: John
testList[0][1]; // That returns: 100
testList[1][0]; // That returns: Maria
testList[1][1]; // That returns: 200
```

That's real good, actually, but now I'm facing a problem when trying to create these multidimensional Lists dynamically.

I want to create a dynamic object List (that works just like this "testList" that I've explained) by getting some data from another List. If I knew the exact number of information to add to the new List I would to it this way:

```
newDynamicList.add([dataSourceList[0], dataSourceList[1]);
```

However, this is not my intention. I want to build a method that can do it dynamically. In other words, take how many parameters comes from the data source list and add them according to the respective "line" ([0][0], [0][1], [0][2], ...).

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
// Where:
// dataList is the data source. Each line has an object.
// numberOfFields reflects how wide the new data List will get.
// iteration is a local variable that is compared to numberOfFields in order to
//           let the code know when to finish that List's line and start a new one.
List getDataParameters(List dataList, int numberOfFields) {
    List tempDataList = new List(); // This list will store the objects in order to build the dataParametersList.
    List dataParametersList = new List(); // This list will be returned to the caller.
    if (dataList.length != 0 && numberOfFields != 0) { // Check for null.
        if (numberOfFields == 1) { // Just one field, do this.
            for (int loop = 0; loop < dataList.length; loop++) {
                dataParametersList.add(dataList[loop]);
            }
        } else { // More than one field.
            int iteration = 1;
            for (int loop = 0; loop < dataList.length; loop++) {
                if (iteration < numberOfFields) {
                    tempDataList.add(dataList[loop]);
                    iteration++;
                } else {
                    tempDataList.add(dataList[loop]);
                    dataParametersList.add(tempDataList); // >>> HERE LIES THE PROBLEM. <<<
                    iteration = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // If there's no data, how to throw exception here?
    }
    return dataParametersList;
}
```

I was assuming that "dataParametersList.add(tempDataList);" would add the objects from tempDataList to dataParametersList like if I was doing it manually. But it just doesn't work.

So the question is: **how can I create these dynamic objects Lists being able to use them like in the first example?**

I'm sorry for the long question, but I tried to be as clear as possible.

EDIT 1: I forgot to say that I know that the code that I provided is wrong by one reason (maybe more): it is adding all the information on tempDataList to dataParametersList on every iteration, since I'm not clearing tempDataList (and clearing it just make things worse, as the latter list becomes null).

EDIT 2:

Example of getDaraParameters(List dataList, int numberOfFields) usage:

```
List dtLst = new List();
dtLst.add("John");
dtLst.add(100);
dtLst.add("Maria");
dtLst.add(200);
print(dtLst); // Returns: [John, 100, Maria, 200]
```

I'm considering using two fields, so the above 4 rows list should look like this after being passed to getDataParameters(dtLst, 2) (assume to print its result):

```
[[John, 100], [Maria, 200]]
```

But I need it to work like the first example of the question, where the multidimensional coordinates work.

Comment: With what data would you call `getDataParameters`. Can you add some demo data you would pass to the method?

Comment: I need to work with sqljocky. getDataParameters would replace "parameters" on line 70 of this Dart code: https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/blob/master/example/example.dart. I've started coding my own class for that, but it will work in that place.

Comment: Can you update your question so that you show how the data looks like that is passed into the method and how the returned data should look like. It's not funny to try to learn that from your code when it doesn't even do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an answer yet but anyway:

Instead of

```dart
for (int loop = 0; loop < dataList.length; loop++) {
  dataParametersList.add(dataList[loop]);
}
```

you could write

```dart
dataParametersList.addAll(dataList);
```

### update

This should do it.

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  print(getDataParameters([], 2));
  print(getDataParameters(["John"], 2));
  print(getDataParameters(["John", 100, "Maria"], 2));
  print(getDataParameters(["John", 100, "Maria", 200], 2));
  print(getDataParameters(["John", 100, "Maria", 200, 10], 2));
}

List getDataParameters(List dataList, int numberOfFields) {
  var result = [];
  int i = 0;
  while(dataList.length > i) {
    result.add(dataList.sublist(i, math.min(i + numberOfFields, dataList.length)));
    i += numberOfFields;
  }
  return result;
}
```

output

```dart
[]
[[John]]
[[John, 100], [Maria]]
[[John, 100], [Maria, 200]]
[[John, 100], [Maria, 200], [10]]
```

`sublist` creates a list containing the items `dataList[i]` to `dataList[i + numberOfFields]`.
This list is added to `result`.
`math.min(i + numberOfFields, dataList.length)` ensures that at the end of `dataList` only as many items are requested as are remaining (when `dataList.length` can't be divided by `numberOfFields` without a remainder.
(When `dataList` has 5 items `sublist(4,6)` would throw an exception)

a shorter version

```dart
List getDataParameters(List l, int f) {
  return new List.generate((l.length / f).ceil(), 
    (i) => l.sublist(i * f, math.min(i * f + f, l.length)));
}
```

Comment: Flawless. Could you explain what's happening inside the "while"?

Comment: I added some explanation.

Comment: I added a shorter version that creates the same result.